# How to allow multiple implementations of a trait on various types of IntoIterator items?

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

Rust doesn't seem to distinguish between different implementations of a trait only if they differ by an associated type.

How can I implement a method on all kinds of collections/iterators, but have specific implementations for each concrete type they contain?

> error: conflicting implementations for trait `Foo` [E0119]

[The code](http://is.gd/995EKa):

```
trait Foo { fn foo(self); }

impl<T> Foo for T 
    where T: IntoIterator<Item=u32> 
{
    fn foo(self) {
        self.into_iter();
    }
}

impl<T> Foo for T 
    where T: IntoIterator<Item=u16> 
{
    fn foo(self) {
        self.into_iter();
    }
}

fn main() {
    vec![0u32].foo();
    vec![0u16].foo();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not do the generic form directly, which is [issue #20400](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400). You'll have to introduce either a trait that can be used as a bound on `T::Item` to merge the two implementations, or wrapper types. E.g. the first one might look like:

```
trait FooIterItem {
    // behaviours needed for Foo impl
}
impl FooIterItem for u32 { ... }
impl FooIterItem for u16 { ... }

impl<T> Foo for T
    where T: IntoIterator, T::Item: FooIterItem
{
    ...
}
```